# ShowMessage with text and integer components

Tags: c++, string, integer, message

I am having trouble in showing a message that is made up of some text combined with an integer

Here is my code:

```
int integerNumberOfImportantAppointments = calCalendar.getNumberOfImportantAppointments();

if (integerNumberOfImportantAppointments > 0)
{
    ShowMessage("You have " + integerNumberOfImportantAppointments + " important appointments. Do you wish to view them?");
}
```

I am getting the following error: E2085 Invalid pointer addition

Can I please have some help in getting this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int integerNumberOfImportantAppointments = calCalendar.getNumberOfImportantAppointments();
if (integerNumberOfImportantAppointments > 0)
{
   // itoa is not standard (like any of this is)
   WCHAR strN[32];
   swprintf(strN, L"%d", integerNumberOfImportantAppointments);

   // not familiar with ShowMessage(), but I *think* this will work.
   ShowMessage("You have " + UnicodeString(strN) + " important appointments. Do you wish to view them?");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `sprintf` or `itoa` (or similar) you are probably better off with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
int iNumberOfImportantAppointments = calCalendar.getNumberOfImportantAppointments();

if (iNumberOfImportantAppointments > 0)
{
    std::istringstream istr;
    istr << "You have " << iNumberOfImportantAppointments << " important appointments. Do you wish to view them?";
    ShowMessage(istr.str().c_str());
}
```

PS. Descriptive variable/function names are good, but there is also such a *too long* names. :)

Answer (score 0):

wht about this:

```
int integerNumberOfImportantAppointments = calCalendar.getNumberOfImportantAppointments();
char buffer[30];
if (integerNumberOfImportantAppointments > 0)
{
itoa (integerNumberOfImportantAppointments,buffer,10);
    ShowMessage("You have " + buffer + " important appointments. Do you wish to view them?");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following errors though: E2193 Too few parameters in call to 'itoa(int,char *,int)' and E2034 Cannot convert 'string' to 'UnicodeString'